# как проверить какой стандарт С99 или С11 использует интегрированнная среда разработки

Tags: c, qtcreator

В общем пользуюсь QtCreator-ом, и хотел бы в виде кода вывести какой стандарт СИ использует мой gcc.

Хотел бы в виде кода запустить, а терминал вывел.

Comment: То есть, Ваша программа должна обратиться к gcc с запросом, на какой стандарт он настроен... А это вообще возможно?

Comment: хм... вот, что попалось… посмотрите... http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1443561.html

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов  а что именно пугает ??? Смысл языка если на нем даже нельзя "споросить " какое его имя . _К примеру "какой язык лучший в мире  ??" ответ "русский язык "_

Comment: лично у меня на такой вопрос будет встречный: в какой категории? разговорные ,машинные, искусственные….

Comment: В gcc можно получить номер версии транслятора. А уж по номеру версии на сайте gcc получить номер стандарта, который эта версия поддерживает. Но "поддерживает" это громко сказано. Несмотря на все усилия по стандартизации, 100% переносимости добиться не получается. Так что номер стандарта не гарантирует, что некоторые конструкции (соответствующие стандарту и транслирующиеся на других трансляторах) будут транслироваться.

Comment: Поддерживаемые: `gcc -v --help 2>&1 | grep -o -e '-std=[^ \.]\+' | sort -u`.

Comment: Значения по умолчанию в конкретном окружении: `info --index-search 'Standards' gcc | sed -e '/The default, if no C/,/^$/!d'`

Comment: ответ писать лень, если кратко, то смотри макрос `__STDC_VERSION__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @Fat-Zer  , надо использовать макрос `__STDC_VERSION__`

Вот код:

```
    printf(" используем версию языка %d\n", __STDC_VERSION__);
```

выводит :

```
используем версию языка 201112
```

что означает 2011 год 12 месяц (также сюда не добавили 20 день :3 )

вот ссылка на сам архив:

https://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-patches@gcc.gnu.org/msg23572.html

Answer (score 1):

Использование стандарта зависит от флагов gcc на этапе компиляции.

```
gcc -std=
```

Доступны такие значения:

```
‘c90’
‘c89’
‘iso9899:1990’
‘iso9899:199409’
‘c99’
‘c9x’
‘iso9899:1999’
‘iso9899:199x’
‘c11’
‘c1x’
‘iso9899:2011’
‘c17’
‘c18’
‘iso9899:2017’
```

По умолчанию при отсутсвии флагов используется

```
-std=gnu11
```

Подробнее [Параметры управления диалектом C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) и [Языковые стандарты, поддерживаемые GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html#Standards)

Конкретно для Qt creator это регулируется в .pro файле добавлением [флагов](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-cc)

```
 QMAKE_CFLAGS += -std=c99
```

Comment: вот пример `gcc -std=c11 main.c -o timer_c11` собирает программу с именем timer_c11 в директории