# Code blocks linux не компилируется алиас типа

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

Вопрос из разряда для начинающих, но учитывая что я под линуксом делаю свой первый проект - думаю это простительно...

Установил среду code::blocks 16.01 стараюсь скомпилировать проект где есть следующая строка:

```
using ulong64 = unsigned long long;
```

В итоге получаю ошибку:

> expected nested-name-specifier before ‘ulong64’

Подскажите возможно нужно где то настройки в окружении поменять ?

Comment: ну например поставить `c++11` и выше? или определить алиас как `typedef` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: я хочу последний стандарт использовать, вроде выставил в Settings -> Compilator C++ 14 (17 от чего то не отобразился) однако ошибка все еще присудствует. Возможно стоит еще где то поменять настройки ?

Comment: Проверить. поддерживает ли ваш компилятор, будь то `gcc` or `clang` данную версию стандарта языка.

Comment: Не подскажите ли способ как это сделать (у меня gcc 7.4, сейчас попробую обновиться)?

Comment: `clang --v`, `gcc --v` и по версии уже найдете, поддерживает ли данная версия стандарт.

Comment: @ヒミコ судя по всему поддерживает.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002102/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82-%d0%a199-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%a111-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0

Comment: Всем спасибо, решил проблему обновлением gcc до 9,01